# alternative liferay theme language

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, template-engine, liferay-theme, liferay-velocity

I need to develop a theme and but i don't like velocity, when creating the theme with the maven archetype i saw a property in pom.xml liferay.theme.type and reading about it seems that you especify vm if your templating language is velocity, but i haven't found an example with another language.

i've tried google but the only alternative i have found is freemarker.

is it posible to use another language to make liferay themes?
if so, which are those languages?
is this property a placeholder for future support for other languages?

Answer (score 1):

The languages available are **velocity**, **freemarker** and **JSP**.

However i suggest you to use velocity (default and considered as best practice until Liferay 6.2) or freemarker (new default and best practice from Liferay 6.2).

Comment: You are right, i haven't got any problem working with the theme in velocity, thanks for yout answer